# Spring mvc unit testing - different forwardedUrl() pattern for tiles views

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, tiles

I am writing unit tests for spring application that uses tiles, for one controller the forwardedUrl is different to view name, and for another controller they are the same but as far as I know the way everything is hooked up is the same.

Can anyone tell me why?

I have a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView root(Locale locale, Model model) {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("base/index/view");
    mv.addObject("display_title", "Home");

    return mv;
}
```

And its unit test:

```
@Test
public void testApplicationRootUrl() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("base/index/view"))
    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/base/index/view.jsp"));         
}
```

The forwardedUrl is /WEB-INF/views/base/index/view.jsp so I would have expected the same pattern to apply to another controller.

Here I have another controller method (in a different controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAllProducts(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Getting all products");

    List<Product> allProducts = productService.getAllProducts();

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("base/product_list/view");

    mv.addObject("products", allProducts);

    return mv;
}
```

And the unit test:

```
@Test
public void testGetAllProducts() throws Exception {
    when(productService.getAllProducts()).thenReturn(getAllProducts());

    mockMvc.perform(get("/products"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(view().name("base/product_list/view"))
    .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/base/product_list/view.jsp"))
    .andExpect(model().attributeExists("products"))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("products", hasSize(1)))
    .andExpect(model().attribute("products", hasItem(
                                    allOf(
                                        hasProperty("id", is(1)),
                                        hasProperty("productName", is("Yellow")),
                                        hasProperty("material", is("Wood"))
                                    )
    )));

    verify(productService, times(1)).getAllProducts();  
}
```

This test fails with the following assertion error, this is what I dont understand as tiles is used throughout the application so I would expect the forwardedUrl to remain consistent in terms of pattern:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Forwarded URL expected:</WEB-INF/views/base/product_list/view.jsp> but was:<base/product_list/view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the slim chance that someone ever wonders about this and wants to know the answer it is because of a difference in the way the mockMvc object is created for the tests.

For the navigation tests which do not have a mocked service I am using the WebApplicationContext:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc =   MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();        
}
```

However for the other tests which require a mocked service I am using Mockito and the standaloneSetup to build the mockMvc object:

```
@Mock
private ProductService productService;

@InjectMocks
private ProductController productController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(productController).build();
}
```

It seems that they return different forwardedUrl's even though tiles is used throughout and there is no difference in the actual controllers, only in the tests.